# zsh running a comand but not from the path

Tags: linux, shell, path, zsh

My zsh is doing something odd, it is running an executable that is not the first executable on my path. I have a wrapper script for ssh but the wrapper is not being invoked while the real ssh binary is being invoked instead.

Some diagnostics:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

$ echo $PATH
/home/user1/bin:/home/user1/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin

$ which ssh
~/bin/ssh

$ builtin which -a ssh
/home/user1/bin/ssh
/usr/bin/ssh

$ alias
l.='ls -d .* --color=tty'
ll='ls -lh'
ls='ls --color=auto'
run-help=man
vi=vim
which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
which-command=whence
zcp='noglob zmv -W -C'
zln='noglob zmv -W -L'
zmv='noglob zmv -W -M'
```

I tried running 'ssh' in bash and my wrapper script was invoked, so it seems like it's a problem with zsh.

Please let me now if any other diagnostic information is needed.

I would really like to know why is it that the $PATH variable is being ignored when I try to invoke ssh.

**Update 1**

Added the output from 'builtin which -a ssh'

Comment: That alias for `which` does irritate me. Can you please post the output of `builtin which -a ssh`? And, as user232011 already pointed out `rehash` (= `hash -r`) is always worth a try when it seems that programs in the PATH are not correctly picked up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the info page, zsh uses a hash table to store the paths to executables.  I am guessing that you did things in this order.

1. Started zsh session
2. Ran standard ssh, this would store the path in the hash table.
3. Created wrapper script.
4. Ran ssh, this picks up the wrong (out of date) path from the hash table.
5. Ran `which ssh`, this just checks the PATH, not the zsh hash table.

The info page for zsh suggests that `hash -r` will clear the hash table, after which the hash table will be rebuilt which should pick up your wrapper script.

When you started bash it didn't share the zsh internal hash of paths, so it just starts looking in the PATH to find things.

Comment: FYI: bash has this hash as well, also use `hash -r` to clear it.